# Graphstory and Neo4jphp

Tags: neo4j, neo4jphp

I have succesfully used neo4jphp library with graphenedb with this simple steps as per documentation (considering that **graphenedb** does not require https)

```
require('vendor/autoload.php'); // or your custom autoloader
// Connecting to a different port or host
$client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client(url, port);
// Connecting using HTTP and Basic Auth
$client->getTransport()
->setAuth('username', 'password');
// Test connection to server
print_r($client->getServerInfo());
```

However, when trying to connect to a **graphstory** instance (of course they both work fine if I call the rest api from browser, the neo4j console works fine etc.) which requires https as follows

```
require('vendor/autoload.php'); // or your custom autoloader
// Connecting to a different port or host
$client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client(url, port);
// Connecting using HTTPS and Basic Auth
$client->getTransport()
->useHttps()
->setAuth('username', 'password');
// Test connection to server
print_r($client->getServerInfo());
```

I get the following error. They should be identical, I can't get why.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Everyman\Neo4j\Exception' with message 'Can't open connection to https://neo-54f500bf2cc7e-364459c455.do-stories.graphstory.com:7473/db/data/' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/graphene/vendor/everyman/neo4jphp/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Transport/Curl.php:91 
Stack trace: 
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/graphene/vendor/everyman/neo4jphp/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Transport.php(95): Everyman\Neo4j\Transport\Curl->makeRequest('GET', '/', NULL) 
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/graphene/vendor/everyman/neo4jphp/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Command.php(64): Everyman\Neo4j\Transport->get('/', NULL) 
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/graphene/vendor/everyman/neo4jphp/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Client.php(828): Everyman\Neo4j\Command->execute() 
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/graphene/vendor/everyman/neo4jphp/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Client.php(464): Everyman\Neo4j\Client->runCommand(Object(Everyman\Neo4j\Command\GetServerInfo)) 
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/graphene/story.php(20): Every in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/graphene/vendor/everyman/neo4jphp/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Transport/Curl.php on line 91
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that neo4jphp is not configuring the TLS part in the cURL request.

I fixed it by downloading the certificate bundle from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html (ca_bundle.crt) and adding the following line to Everyman\Neo4j\Transport\Curl.php, function makeRequest:

```
$options[CURLOPT_CAINFO] = "your/path/to/ca-bundle.crt";
```

I've created an issue on GitHub for this: https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/issues/171

Answer (score 0):

I'm the CTO/Lead Dev at Graph Story. Sorry to hear you're having troubles. I've actually just taken a look at your instance and things seem OK from the server side.

Without additional info it's hard to say if there's an issue with your sample connection code. Considering that you've used that same library to connect to GrapheneDB in the past, I think the chances an error in the sample code is low.

Based on the current state of your instance and on the exception thrown by Neo4jPHP, my guess is that port 7473 may be blocked on your network. You can confirm that with local tech support or by switching to a network where you know port 7473 is open and trying to connect again.